# Problem with dynamic arrays (I suppose) for numbers from 200

Tags: c++

I am writing an algorithm which outputs all prime numbers in range `[3; n]`. Take a look at my code and I will explain the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the value of n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int k = (n - 2) / 2 + 1;

    bool* nums = new bool[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) nums[i] = true; 

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        int j = i;

        while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= k)
        {
            nums[i + j + 2 * i * j] = false;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i])
        {
            cout << 2 * i + 1 << endl;
        }
    }

    delete[]nums;
    nums = NULL;

    system("pause>0");
}
```

For `n < 200` everything works well. But for `n >= 200` I get the error:

```
Debug Error!
<...>
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#764) at
0x008655A0.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

How to fix it? I am sure that this problem is surrounding dynamic array `nums`.

Comment: `while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= k)` should be `while (i + j + 2 * i * j < k)`

Comment: @stark It indeed works! Thanks. I think I understood the problem.

Comment: also consider : std::vector<bool> nums(200,true); to give you a dynamically allocated array of 200 bools directly initialized to true; The rest of the code (including fix above) stays the same but you can remove the delete. (If you can write code without new/delete that's preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop

```
    while (i + j + 2 * i * j <= k)
    {
        nums[i + j + 2 * i * j] = false;
        j++;
    }
```

might access `nums` out of bounds in the last iteration, when `i+j+2*i*j == k`, because the last valid index is `k-1`.

Out of bounds access is undefined behavior in C++, hence your code might appear to work for `n < 200`. Also, the index, `i+j+2*i*j`, increases by `1+2*i` in each iteration, hence there are values for `n` where the out-of-bounds access does not occur (eg when `k` is prime).

To make the condition a little less error prone, you can consider to rewrite the loop like this:

```
 for (int m = ... ; m < k; m+= 1+2*i) {
     nums[m] = false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation lad!

Comment: @RodionIskhakov the way to say "thanks" is to upvote the answer. And don't forget to accept the answer that you think answers your question by clicking the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 1):

The array is allocated to `k` elements. Arrays are 0-indexed, so valid indexes are [0..k-1], thus `k` itself is not a valid index. As such, using `>= k` in the inner `while` loop will allow it to go out of bounds on the last iteration, writing data to surrounding memory. You need to use `< k` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation lad!